# Decaying function terminology

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function. What does it mean by "$f$ decays at $\pm\infty$?" Does it mean $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0?$

Comment: By itself, yes. "Decays" also gives us some leeway to say "decays at a certain rate", which is useful in certain situations.

Comment: So decay at infinity $=$ vanish at infinity?

Comment: That's correct.